# How can i create a checksum from a DataTable object?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, checksum, md5sum

I have a datatable with 45-50 columns and 45-50 rows and i want to create a checksum text or md5, sha1, i don't know which one is better. I'll create that text and search for it in database if there is one more of it. But the text length must be between 100-200 character, i don't know if i can do it. So what's your opinions about that and how can i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Why such a long checksum? SHA1 is only 160 bits which turns out to be 20 characters. The hash collision can be achieved by brute force methods in 2^80 (1,208,925,819,614,629,174,706,176) tries, and by targeted attacks in about 2^69 tries. More information can be found on Schneier's blog: http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/cryptanalysis_o.html

Comment: 100-200 character is most. if i can handle it with 20 characters no problem. but i don't want to create a checksum from datatable object also want to check rows and fields. then i can find if there is another of it.

Answer (score 5):

The following should do:

```
// Serialize the table
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(DataTable));
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, table);
byte[] serializedData = memoryStream.ToArray();

// Calculte the serialized data's hash value
var SHA = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] hash = SHA.ComputeHash(serializedData);

// Convert the hash to a base 64 string
string hashAsText = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
```

Note that we are serializing the whole table, not only its field values and that the table must have a name in order to allow serialization

Comment: is this example for .net 4.0 because i can't find DataContractSerializer and XmlDictionaryWriter objects. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @mehmetserif add a reference to system.runtime.serialization

Comment: I know this is old, but what is the writer for? It's not used in the rest of the code...

Answer (score 2):

Well algorithm wise, either [MD5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5.aspx) or [SHA1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1.aspx) (Newer) will work for a checksum.

Couple of things though:

- Why does the text length need to be between 100-200 characters? It's still a hash, and portrays the same information no matter then length.
- What are you looking to do?
- What part do you require help with?

Answer (score 0):

first you should do a binary serialization of your dataset

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/7700/serializedeserialize-a-datatable.aspx

for calculating sha1 :

```
/// <summary>
/// Calculates SHA1 hash
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">input string</param>
/// <param name="enc">Character encoding</param>
/// <returns>SHA1 hash</returns>
public static string CalculateSHA1(string text, Encoding enc)
{
    byte[] buffer = enc.GetBytes(text);
    SHA1CryptoServiceProvider cryptoTransformSHA1 = 
    new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    string hash = BitConverter.ToString(
        cryptoTransformSHA1.ComputeHash(buffer)).Replace("-", "");

    return hash;
}
```

or md5 :

http://www.spiration.co.uk/post/1203/MD5%20in%20C%23%20-%20works%20like%20php%20md5%28%29%20example

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a hash on a dataRow within a datatable use drRow.GetHashCode().